# Do Ranger Beast Master Primal Companions use Strength or Wisdom for Attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger

The general rule of melee weapon attacks is, that you use STR unless otherwise specified.

The Spell attack modifier of a Ranger is based on Wisdom.

The Primal Companions from TCoE use the Ranger's Spell Attack Modifier but make Melee Weapon Attacks.

My question is, does the use of the Spell Attack Modifier without any further comment suffice to say the attack is made with Wisdom, or does it still use STR by default?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, Apfeljunge666! You might want to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, you use the ranger's spell attack modifier

As you noted, the language is (from Beast of the Land):

> Maul. Melee Weapon Attack: your spell attack modifier to hit

"Your spell attack modifier" means just that. The specific rule defined in the primal companions' stat blocks [beats the general rule](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#SpecificBeatsGeneral) determining melee weapon attacks.

For rangers, the [spell attack modifier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#SpellcastingAbility5) is defined as:

> Spell attack modifier = your proficiency bonus + your Wisdom modifier

So, yes, the attack is made with Wisdom, not Strength.

Comment: Thought of a PC example where it matters btw: Barbarian's Reckless Attack and Rage bonus damage both *require* attack roll using Strength. They aren't gonna apply to a Beast Master Companion, but there might be some other feature that does

Comment: Yeah, there might be some edge cases.

Comment: The reason i asked was such an edge case. the Spell Guardian of Nature. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Are you after if *you* use *guardian of nature* to transform into a Primal Beast, were you hoping your Primal Companion would get advantage on Strength-based attack rolls?

Comment: with the Share Spell feature, both the Ranger and the beast would benefit from Guardian of Nature at the same time.